# Java class will not compile

Tags: java, httpconnection

I am getting a couple errors I cannot seem to fix... This is example code, so I'm confused what's going on. The error's are commented to the side of the lines where they show up.

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;


public class Connect {
    URL url;
    URLConnection urlConnection;
    DataOutputStream outStream;
    DataInputStream inStream;

    // Build request body
    String body = "fname=" + URLEncoder.encode("Atli", "UTF-8"); //Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token


    // Create connection
    url = new URL("http://192.168.1.68/test/POST/post.php");
    urlConnection = url.openConnection();
    ((HttpURLConnection)urlConnection).setRequestMethod("POST");
    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", ""+ body.length());

    // Create I/O streams
    outStream = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
    inStream = new DataInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

    // Send request
    outStream.writeBytes(body);
    outStream.flush();
    outStream.close();

    // Get Response
    // - For debugging purposes only!
    String buffer;
    while((buffer = inStream.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(buffer);
    }

    // Close I/O streams
    inStream.close();
    outStream.close();

}
```

giving an error of:

```
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody
```

Anybody see something obvious that I don't?

On a side note, if the php echoes back html code, upon running this class, is java capable of understanding the html code?

Comment: What IDE do you use? What did you try to fix it? Please don't just throw source at us and request fixes. In general, most IDEs make it easy to produce syntactically correct code.

Comment: @MichaelSchmeißer the error is in the last line of the source code...

Comment: @Alnitak Just saw it and edited my comment, but please provide further information anyway.

Comment: @MichaelSchmeißer I'm not the poster - I was just telling you how to find the poster's error.

Comment: @Alnitak Oh ^^ ok, thank you. Your answer to the question seems plausible too.

Comment: @MichaelSchmeißer p.s. not everyone uses an IDE.  I write code almost exclusively using `vi` and command line compilers.

Comment: in future please put error messages in your question _text_, and not in the source code.  Your error was initially invisible because you had to scroll the source code to find it!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't put code directly in the class body - you have to wrap it inside a member function.

If this is intended to be a standalone program that member function should be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want that code to be executed on construction of an instance of "Connect" you should put it in the constructor. This also fixes all of your errors.

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class Connect {

    URL url;
    URLConnection urlConnection;
    DataOutputStream outStream;
    DataInputStream inStream;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public Connect() {
        // Build request body
        try {
            String body = "fname=" + URLEncoder.encode("Atli", "UTF-8");


            // Create connection
            url = new URL("http://192.168.1.68/test/POST/post.php");
            urlConnection = url.openConnection();
            ((HttpURLConnection) urlConnection).setRequestMethod("POST");

            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + body.length());

            // Create I/O streams
            outStream = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            inStream = new DataInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

            // Send request
            outStream.writeBytes(body);
            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();

            // Get Response
            // - For debugging purposes only!
            String buffer;

            // DataInputStream.readLine is deprecated
            // use the BufferedReader class instead
            while ((buffer = inStream.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(buffer);
            }

            // Close I/O streams
            inStream.close();
            outStream.close();
        } catch (IOException iOException) {
            // there are many methods that can throw errors in this code,
            // you should catch those errors
        }
    }
}
```